# When is a ScriptBlock not a ScriptBlock?

Tags: powershell, scope, scriptblock

I do not mean to sound too cute with the question, but that really is the question at hand. Consider the following two functions defined in a PowerShell module Test.psm1 installed under $env:PSModulePath:

```
function Start-TestAsync
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([ScriptBlock]$Block, [string]$Name = '')   
    Start-Job { Start-Test -Name $using:Name -Block $using:Block }
}

function Start-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([ScriptBlock]$Block, [string]$Name = '')
    # do some work here, including this:
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block
}
```

After importing the module, I can then run the synchronous function...

```
PS> Start-Test -Name "My Test" -Block { ps | select -first 9 }
```

...and it displays appropriate output from Get-Process.

However, when I attempt to run the asynchronous version...

```
PS> $testJob=Start-TestAsync -Name "My Test" -Block { ps | select -first 9 }
```

...and then review its output...

```
PS> Receive-Job $testJob
```

... it fails at just bringing in the parameter to the Start-Test function, reporting it cannot convert a String to a ScriptBlock. Thus, `-Block $using:Block` is passing a String rather than a ScriptBlock!

After some experimentation, I did find a workaround. If I modify Start-Test so that the type of the $Block parameter is [string] instead of [ScriptBlock] -- and then convert that string back to a block to feed to Invoke-Command...

```
function Start-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$Block, [string]$Name = '')
    $myBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create($Block)
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $myBlock
}
```

I then obtain the correct result when I run the same commands from above:

```
PS> $testJob=Start-TestAsync -Name "My Test" -Block { ps | select -first 9 }
PS> Receive-Job $testJob
```

Is the `using` scope working correctly in my initial example (converting a ScriptBlock to a string)? The limited documentation on it ([about_Remote_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149005.aspx), [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)) offers little guidance.
Ultimately, is there a way to make Start-Test work when its $Block parameter is typed as a [ScriptBlock]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is useful to know (thanks, @KeithHill) that what I was seeing was a known issue--sorry, I meant "by design"--my real question had not been answered (*"Ultimately, is there a way to make Start-Test work when its $Block parameter is typed as a [ScriptBlock]?"*)

The answer came to me suddenly last night:

```
function Start-TestAsync
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([ScriptBlock]$Block, [string]$Name = '')   
    Start-Job {
        $myBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create($using:Block);
        Start-Test -Name $using:Name -Block $myBlock  }
}

function Start-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([ScriptBlock]$Block, [string]$Name = '')   
    # do some work here, including this:
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block
}
```

Notice that in Start-TestAsync I internally allow the serialization to occur ($using:Block), converting the ScriptBlock to a String, then immediately re-convert it (Create) to a ScriptBlock, and can then safely pass that on to Start-Test as a genuine ScriptBlock.
To me, this is a significant improvement over the workaround in my question because now the public APIs on both functions are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently by design: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/685749/passing-scriptblocks-to-the-job-as-an-argument-cannot-process-argument-transformation-on-parameter

The workaround (from the link above) is to use `[ScriptBlock]::Create()`:

> This happens because the $ScriptToNest scriptblock is getting converted into a string 
>      because of how PowerShell serialization works. You can work around this by explicitly 
>      creating the scriptblock. Replace the param() block in your $OuterScriptblock with the 
>      following ($ip is the input):
>
> ```
> [scriptblock]$OuterScriptblock = {
> param($ip)
> [ScriptBlock]$ScriptToRun = [ScriptBlock]::Create($ip)
> ```

This would be your work-around (as you've found):

```
function Start-TestAsync
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([ScriptBlock]$Block, [string]$Name = '')
    Start-Job { Start-Test -Name $using:Name -Block $using:Block }
}

function Start-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($Block, [string]$Name = '')
    # do some work here, including this:
    $sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($Block)
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, Keith, but that is essentially what I reported in my question, no? I see only one cosmetic difference, in that you omit a type on the $Block parameter entirely where I had it as a string... I do appreciate the Connect reference, though.

Comment: Yup, but for future reference for other folks it is nice to have the work-around in one of the answers.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't quite answer your question, but I think you could simplify this a lot by putting it into one function:

```powershell
function Start-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ScriptBlock]$Block, 
        [string]$Name = '',
        [Switch]$Async
    )
    # do some work here, including this:
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block -AsJob:$Async
}
```

Since `Invoke-Command` can already start a job for you, you can have your function accept an `-Async` switch, then pass its value to the `-AsJob` switch.

#### Invoke Synchronous

```powershell
Start-Test -Block { ps | select -first 9 }
```

#### Invoke Asynchronous

```powershell
Start-Test -Block { ps | select -first 9 } -Async
```

#### Speculation

As for why that actual thing you're seeing is happening, I'm not certain, but I think it might be related to nesting the script blocks, though I'm unable to do a proper test at the moment.

Comment: Good suggestion, @briantist! Unfortunately, that would not work in my particular circumstances only because I have more than the single Invoke-Command that needs to be run as a job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're seeing this is that the purpose of $using is to expand the **values** of of local variables inside the script block prior to it being used on the remote system - it doesn't actually create those variables in the the remote session.  The closest thing a scriptblock has to a value is it's command text.